# Trouble writing a header line with a comma to an Excel csv file

Tags: excel, csv, fortran, intel-fortran

I'm trying to write a simple header line in Intel Fortran (containing actual content commas) to an Excel csv. What I'd like to see in the first two columns is:

```
FMG(1,1) FMG(2,1)
```

Enclosing each term in quotes "`FGM(i,j)`" worked when I did it line by line:

```
Code:   write (*,*) "FMG(1,1), kg/s (O2):   ", FMG(1,1)
Output: FMG(1,1), kg/s (O2):     0.129000000000000
```

Some of the things I've tried include:

```
code:               write (10,*) "FMG(1,1)","FMG(2,1)"
csv column output:  FMG(1   1)FMG(2   1)

code:               write (10,*) "FMG(1,1)" , "FMG(2,1)"
csv column output:  FMG(1   1)FMG(2   1)  (same thing)

code:               write (10,*) "  FMG(1,1),"   "FMG(2,1)"
csv column output:  FMG(1   1)    FMG(2,1)
```

got the 2nd one correctly

Comment: Welcome, please  take the [tour] and read [ask]. Your question is really hard to read and understand. Please show a real piece of code, properly formatted. Use the `{}` button to format code. Show how you open the file. Show the *actual exact* output. Please ask some question, you did not ask one.

Comment: I agree with Vladimir that your question is unclear. I wonder if when you show the "csv column output" you're showing what Excel displays, not what's in the text file. Note that Excel will consider commas to be a delimiter when a CSV file is opened.

My other comment is that you should never use list-directed output when you care about formatting.

Answer (score 0):

CSV by name means Comma Separated Values.  If you output "FMG(1,1),FMG(1,2)" then removing the commas, you will get

```
FMG(1
1)
FMG(1
2)
```

which is what you are seeing.  To include the commas, the strings need to be enclosed in quotes.  If you write

```
write (10,*) '"FMG(1,1)","FMG(2,1)"'
```

it might achieve what you are looking for.

Comment: Cup,thanks for your help, gets me closer, except pesky double quotes now surround each group of text, at least on the screen.  What'll do when it's writing to a .csv file is likely another thing.  Key is I can live with the double quotes for now.  Thanks again.